# How to iterate and parse JSON from query in Express/Jade?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs so I'm thinking this is simple but I cannot find a way to pass the JSON data from a select query to the Jade view. I am using Node.js Tools for Visual Studio to create the project which uses Express + Jade. Here is my `index.js` file:

```
exports.products = function (req, res) {
var request = new sql.Request(connection);
console.log("Connection successful.");
request.query('SELECT * FROM product', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data[i]);
    res.render('products', {
        title: 'Products', 
        year: new Date().getFullYear(), 
        message: 'Products page with all devices',
        name: 'Rodney',
        result: data[i]
    });    
});
```

This the view I'm using in Jade to render the results:

```
- product = typeof(result) != 'undefined' ? result : { }
for p in product
  h3 #{product.Name}
```

I am getting the error `i is not defined` which makes sense, but I can only show 1 record if I change it to `result: data[0]`.
Here is a sample of how the JSON is structured:
`{ Id: 56,
  Name: 'Motion',
  ModelString: '1234-G',
  Description: 'Motion Front Door',
  Released: true,
  BoardId: 29,
  CreateDate: Wed Aug 05 2015 06:29:31 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),
  SerialNumberCode: 'AAA',
  ExtensionId: 9,
  SKU: '1234-G',
  CurrentTest: false,
  ModelEncodingNumber: -1 }`

How can I show all records with the column `name`?

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually directly forward the data to your `res.render` method like this:

```
res.render('products', {
    ...
    products: data
});

// in view.jade
for p in product
    h3 #{product.Name}
```

If you only need the names of your product, you can loop over your data first, collect the names and store them in another list:

```
var allNames = data.map(function(element) {
    return element.Name;
})

res.render('products', {
    ...
    names: allNames
});  

// view.jade
for name in names
    h3 #{name}
```

Comment: Very nice! I used your second approach and worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just passing `data`?

EDIT:

Hope this works

```
- productList = typeof(result) != 'undefined' ? 
result : { }
for product in productList
  for p in product
    h3 #{p.Name}
```

Comment: Yes. When I pass data, I get the output to console, but not in the view itself. There is nothing there.

Comment: Im taking a wild guess on the structure of 'data'. I updated my answer

Comment: I changed `result: data` and then added your code on the Jade side and now get an `Unexpected token` error in an `acorn.js` file.

Comment: Ok It'd more helpful if you can put what 'data' prints out in your question.

Comment: Ok. Can u try again. I made a small change